# AngularJs how to access attributes of objects with numbers in its name?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, angularjs-scope, angularjs-controller

I have an  issue to access object property that has numbers in it's name , below sample code is a response of Pinterest API , i can access each property except the images URL . error raised because of 237x object ,apprciate your help

Response output 
showing images object -->237x--->url,width,height

```
var pinterestitems =null ;
      Comics.pinterest().success(function (response) {
      $scope.pinterestitems = response.data.pins;
      console.log(response.data.pins.images.237x.url); //description ,link,images.url
      //console.log(response.data.pins);
```

my code raise an error when referencing URL attribute
console.log(response.data.pins.images.237x.url)
error message :
Controllers.js:28 Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token.

the error underlined (237x)

Comment: Many thanks Patrick , all good , issue solved.